# Bat как удалить символ из строки зная его код в 1251 кодировке?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть txt файл который содержит значения показанные ниже. Кодировка файла 1251. Как из каждой строки файла удалить символ пробела зная его код `<A0>` в кодировке 1251? Используя bat файл. Кодировка консоли windows 866.

[image: Исходный файл]

На выходе должен получить файл такого вида.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удаление пробела по средствам `SET variable=!variable: =!` Не работает.

Сейчас скрипт имеет такой вид.

```
@ECHO OFF
chcp 1251

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

erase lb_2_task_1_boofer_1.txt  
erase lb_2_task_1_PID.txt
erase lb_2_task_1_MEM.txt

tasklist /NH /FO csv /FI "imagename eq chrome.exe" > lb_2_task_1_boofer_1.txt

SET FILE=lb_2_task_1_boofer_1.txt
SET MAX_PROGRAM_MEM=50000

FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%a IN (%FILE%) do (
  SET PID=%%b
  SET PID=!PID:~1,-1! :Убрал кавычки для PID
  SET MEM=!PID: =!    :Убрал все пробелы
  @ECHO !PID!>>lb_2_task_1_PID.txt :Вывел в файл
  SET MEM=%%e
  SET MEM=!MEM:~1,-3! :Убрал кавычку в начале и кавычку КБ и пробел сзади
  :SET MEM=!MEM: =!   :Для удаления пробела между 108 792 это не подходит
  :@ECHO !MEM!
  @ECHO !MEM!>>lb_2_task_1_MEM.txt
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: А powershell-то тут при чем? Кстати, не думали на него переписать ваш скрипт?

Comment: `SET MEM=!PID: =!    :Убрал все пробелы` - точно SET **MEM** =...?

Comment: Не понятно назначение скрипта. Нужно составить список ID-процесса и занимаемого им объема оперативной памяти? Или просто список объемов памяти подпроцессов Chrome выраженный в кбайтах (без пробелов)?

Comment: Как я понял - получить список занимаемой памяти, в виде чисел без разделителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, я догадываюсь зачем вся эта свистопляска с файлами и кодировками.

Но считаю, что если заданы такие начальные условия:

- использование утилиты tasklist;
- получения параметров памяти в КБ (то есть строки длиной не более 15
  символов.

То создание временных файлов **не нужно** в принципе. Все можно впихнуть в пару вложенных циклов.
В первом цикле извлекаются значения столбца **размера памяти**. Во втором - извлекаются только цифры.

```
@echo off
@SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in ('@tasklist /NH /FO csv /FI "imagename eq chrome.exe"') do (
@set _str=%%e
@set _str=!_str:~1,-3!
 @set str=
 @For /l %%g in (0,1,15) do (
  @Set "_char=!_str:~%%g,1!"
  @set p=!_char!
  @if not defined _char @set "p="
  @if 0 gtr !_char! @set "p="
  @if 9 lss !_char! @set "p="
  @set str=!str!!p!
 )
@echo !str!
)
@setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

Comment: Вообще, причиной появления вопроса в таком виде является некорректное отображение на экране разделится разрядов числа памяти утилитой tasklist (символ FF). Если на обрабатываемой системе   есть возможность воспользоваться другой утилитой. То предлагаю взамен следующую команду: **wmic process where (name="chrome.exe") get WorkingSetSize**

Answer (score 3):

Символ с кодом 0xA0 - это не [обычный] пробел, пробел имеет код 0x20.

Соответственно, можно попробовать сделать `SET MEM=!MEM:<Alt+(0160)>=!`, где <Alt+(0160)> - это цифры 0160, набранные на NumPad'е при нажатом Alt.

Пример:

```
@echo off
chcp 1251
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set test=Demo<Alt+(0160)>String
echo %test%
set test=!test:<Alt+(0160)>=!
echo %test%
```

У меня отображается так:

```
Текущая кодовая страница: 1251
Demo String
DemoString
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью программы. Придётся прикладывать exe файл, но зато в одну строку
nhrt.exe -set:"\xA0" -e file.txt